# How to use the same view multiple times in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I have a user control **StudentView.xaml** that is something like this:

```
<Grid>
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding StudentName}"/>
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding StudentID}"/>
</Grid>
```

I also have a model **Student.cs** that is something like this:

```
private string _StudentName = null;
public string StudentName{
 get => _StudentName;
 set {_StudentName = value; OnPropertyChange("StudentName");}
}

private string _StudentID = null;
public string StudentID{
 get => _StudentID ;
 set {_StudentID = value; OnPropertyChange("StudentID");}
}
```

In my ViewModel **MainViewModel** I have a collection of **Student**'s like this:

```
ObservableCollection<Student> Students = new ObservableCollection<Student>();

// Do something here to populate Students

NumOfStudents = Students.Count();
```

In my main window, I have something like this:

```
<StackPanel>
 <local:StudentView/>
</StackPanel>
```

I am very new to WPF and seeking for help. I know how to bind **local:StudentView** to one student. My question is that is there a way to use **local:StudentView** as many as time as **NumOfStudents**. For example, if I have 5 students, the main window will display **StudentView** 5 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want do something like...

```
<ItemsControl
    ItemsSource="{Binding Students}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:StudentView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Be aware that StackPanel is the default ItemsPanel. You do not need to set it like this.

Answer (score 0):

What you most likely want is a [ItemsControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol?view=windowsdesktop-7.0).  You will set the ItemsSource property to your observable collection and define a [ItemTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) to define how the items should be rendered (StudentView.xaml).  Finally, since you are using a StackPanel, that will be defined as your ItemsPanelTemplate.